# primeng multiselect lazy load value on filtering

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to show the filtered value on multiselect from the API response.

If I search something and the searched value is not exists on the options variable immediately it shows `No results found`. But, instead of showing `No results found` I am trying to wait until the API complete, if the response has some datathen show the corresponding value, or else, show the `No results found` message.

After clearing the searched value from the multiselect's input-box, updated dropdown is displaying properly with new value.

I have created the [stack-blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-f8mwad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I am not sure, what I am missing on this code. In the stackblitz I have added the settimeout to perform some time delay and push the values to the options variable.

.html

```
<p-multiSelect
  (onFilter)="load($event)"
  [options]="msOptions"
  defaultLabel="Select..."
></p-multiSelect>
```

.ts

```
load(event) {
  console.log('event is ', event);
  setTimeout((r) => {
    if (event.filter.includes('xyz')) {
      for (let i of [4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 43]) {
        this.msOptions.push({ label: 'xyz' + i, value: 'xyz' + i });
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}
}
```